# Android's Processes

Tags: android

I need to know some information about all android's basic processes, such as

- com.android.phone
- android.process.acore
- com.android.mms
- com.android.alarmclock
- com.android.calendar
- android.process.media
- com.android.voicedialer
- android.process.im

unfortunately, i could not find any good information on the internet
Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Do you want to see the source code and file details of above packages?

Comment: It might help if you say what information you need!

Comment: I want to know which task is for each process?